# How do i calculate $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h^2)-f(a+h)}{h}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

All do i know about this problem is that f can be derived in "a".

What troubles me is the h squared,i just can't get rid of it or make it useful,no matter what i do, i always end up with it giving me an undefined limit, so it stays like that,any idea on how to get rid of it? or any rule i can use to make this easy?

Answer (score 10):

You can write
$$\frac{f(a + h^2) - f(a+h)}{h} = h \cdot \frac{f(a+h^2) - f(a)}{h^2} - \frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h}$$
and compute these two limits individually.

Comment: yup worked,thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

This is
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h^2)-f(a)}{h}-\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}.$$
If $f'(a)$ exists, this is
$$\lim_{h\to0}h\left(\frac{f(a+h^2)-f(a)}{h^2}\right)-f'(a)=-f'(a).$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h^2)-f(a)}h=\lim_{h\to0}h\frac{f(a+h^2)-f(a)}{h^2}=h\times f'(a)=0.$$

Comment: Can you explain why it would be kosher to say $\lim h[K(h^2)] = \lim h(\lim K(w)) = \lim h*f'(x) = 0$?  Is it okay to split a limit that way.

Comment: Thanks btw u helped me a lot!

Comment: I see you using "$f\left(a + h^2\right) - f\left(a\right)$" in the numerator compared to the question's "$f\left(a + h^2\right) - f\left(a + h\right)$" based on the value split, but you may wish to make this clear in your answer.

Comment: @fleablood Yes, it is fine, as long as both limits exist.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Not need anymore, given the answer provided by Umberto P.

Comment: But the answer by Umberto P. gives $-f'(a)$ and your answer is $0.$

Comment: No, my answer is not $0$. I did not provide an answer. I provided a hint to help the OP to obtain the answer.